# Why do we write n/=10 in an armstorng program?

Tags: java, bluej

I am a beginner at bluej and just came across a program to find whether a number is armstrong number or not! i just wanted to ask **what do we mean by `n /= 10` in the for loop and why do we write it?**

```
class arm {

   public static void main() throws IOException {

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     int d, n, dup, sum = 0;
     System.out.println("Enter a NO.:");
     n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     for(dup = n; n > 0; n /= 10) {
        d = n % 10;
        sum = sum + d*d*d;
     }
     if (sum == dup)
         System.out.println(dup + " is an armstrong no.");
     else
         System.out.println(dup + " is not an armstrong no.");
   }
}
```

Comment: `n /= 10` gives `n` containing all digits except the last. It's just a way of iterating over digits.

Comment: `n /= 10` is equivalent to `n = n / 10`

Answer (score 3):

```
n /= 10
```

is a shortcut to :

```
n = n / 10
```

In the same way that `n+=1` is `n = n+1`

Comment: You can even have `n >>>= 10`, which is the longest Java operator (okay, apart from `instanceof`)